# " Thank " cannot be used alone

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who always says "Thank" instead of "Thanks" or "Thank you".
For example, when I ask: " Do you like to come?", his answer is: "Thank. I am busy".

Can you explain why "Thank" cannot be alone?  Surely it must be “Thanks”, or “Thanks to you” or “Thank you”.

Comment: Because to Thank is the verb and "Thank you" and "Thanks" are the idiomatic expressions that uses that verb.

Answer (score 0):

This use of the word is a kind of solecism. Yes, it is not standard English.  You could go on criticising your friend’s personal habit.  It is a kind of social mannerism, with which all her/his acquaintances are familiar.  But the more you correct her/him, the more s/he will persist.  “S/he only does it to annoy, because s/he knows it teases.”

Comment: This addresses the non-standard usage of OP's 'friend', not how the use of 'Thanks' (almost certainly in line with 'Congratulations' and 'Best Wishes' etc) rather than 'Thank.' etc developed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth At least this one cannot be traced to Latin ‘gratiam ago’, as far as I know.  The connection with ‘congratulations’ is tempting, except that (a) the nouns cites all have a recognised singular, unlike ‘thanks’.  I need further research, but I wonder if it goes back to Christian ceremony in which  whole congregations gave ‘thanks unto the Lord’ once a week.